# How to solve error H10 Heroku on deployed project running on ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi

I get these errors when deploying my ASP.NET Core Web API project to heroku using Docker :

[image]

Logs are :

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Same error here, I was looking for a solution and I guess is something with the initial routing and a config file. I have found a node.js solution but nothing with netcore yet.